# EF Power Tool - Custom Files

Tags: entity-framework

I have updated the EF power tool tt files to generate code the way I like it, but I would also like it to generate enum's from the database.  Enum support in the latest EF is good if you use database-first or design-first, it nicely creates an enum class for you and hooks it all up, but in code-first it does not.  If you want to have the table and an enum, you have to do some things yourself.  I am hoping to find a simple way to run an enum tt for tables that I specify to create an enum class that my modified EF power tool tt's then uses.